# Error en Pivot Table Invalid identifier

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, pivot

Estoy realizando una consulta en Sql Developer, en la que quiero hacer un Pivot pero obtengo el error ORA 00904 invalid identifier.

Esta consulta me devuelve la siguiente tabla:

```
SELECT * FROM (
select RangeOfLength,
   SUM(volume) vol,
   COUNT(DISTINCT(Cod)) QtyCodes,
   plant
    from (
select CASE
     WHEN b.length >= 0 and b.length <= 500 THEN '0To500'
     WHEN b.length >= 501 and b.length <= 1000 THEN '501To1000'
     WHEN b.length >= 1001 and b.length <= 2000 THEN '1001To2000'
     WHEN b.length >= 2001 and b.length <= 3000 THEN '2001To3000'
     WHEN b.length >= 3001 and b.length <= 4000 THEN '3001To4000'
     WHEN b.length >= 4001 and b.length <= 5000 THEN '4001To5000'
     WHEN b.length >= 5001 and b.length <= 6000 THEN '5001To6000'
     WHEN b.length >= 6001 and b.length <= 7000 THEN '6001To7000'
     WHEN b.length >= 7001 and b.length <= 8000 THEN '7001To8000'
     WHEN b.length >= 8001 and b.length <= 99999 THEN '8001To99999'
     END AS RangeOfLength,
   w.plant,
   w.volume,
   y.Cod
    from T56W w, T56X x, T56Y y, T57B b
      where w.PART_NBR = x.PART_NBR 
      AND w.PLANT_ID = x.PLANT_ID
      ANDx.BF = y.BF 
      AND x.PART_NBR = y.PART_NBR
      AND x.PLANT_ID = y.PLANT_ID
      AND y.Cod = b.Cod
      AND y.PLANT_ID = b.PLANT_ID))
      GROUP By RangeOfLength
      ODDER BY 1)
```

[image: Consulta1]

El Pivot que quiero hacer es para agregar las plantas con el volumen que tiene cada planta en ese rango de longitud.

[image: Pivot]

Para ello estoy tratando de modificar la consulta anterior de esta forma:

```
SELECT * FROM (
select RangeOfLength,
   SUM(volume) vol,
   COUNT(DISTINCT(Cod)) QtyCodes,
   plant
     from (
     select CASE
     WHEN b.length >= 0 and b.length <= 500 THEN '0To500'
     WHEN b.length >= 501 and b.length <= 1000 THEN '501To1000'
     WHEN b.length >= 1001 and b.length <= 2000 THEN '1001To2000'
     WHEN b.length >= 2001 and b.length <= 3000 THEN '2001To3000'
     WHEN b.length >= 3001 and b.length <= 4000 THEN '3001To4000'
     WHEN b.length >= 4001 and b.length <= 5000 THEN '4001To5000'
     WHEN b.length >= 5001 and b.length <= 6000 THEN '5001To6000'
     WHEN b.length >= 6001 and b.length <= 7000 THEN '6001To7000'
     WHEN b.length >= 7001 and b.length <= 8000 THEN '7001To8000'
     WHEN b.length >= 8001 and b.length <= 99999 THEN '8001To99999'
     END AS RangeOfLength,
   w.plant,
   w.volume,
   y.Cod
    from T56W w, T56X x, T56Y y, T57B b
    where w.PART_NBR = x.PART_NBR 
     AND w.PLANT_ID = x.PLANT_ID
     ANDx.BF = y.BF 
     AND x.PART_NBR = y.PART_NBR
     AND x.PLANT_ID = y.PLANT_ID
     ANDy.Cod = b.Cod
     AND y.PLANT_ID = b.PLANT_ID))
     PIVOT 
      (SUM(volume) SUM, SUM(plant) FOR plant
       IN ('Plant 1',
           'Plant 2',
           'Plant 3',
           'Plant 4',
           'Plant 5',
           'Plant 6',
           'Plant 7'))
    GROUP BY RangeOfLength
```

Esta consulta me tira error en la linea 3 ORA-00904: "volume": invalid identifier

He modificado la consulta ahora no me da error, pero me da 70 columnas esto porque son 7 plantas * 10 rangos de longitud que estoy evaluando = 70, entonces me faltaria agrupar por rango de longitud en el Pivot.

Esta es la nueva consulta:

```
SELECT * FROM (
select RangeOfLength,
   report_plant Plant,
   COALESCE(SUM(volume),0) vol,
   COUNT(DISTINCT(Cod)) QtyCodes
     from (
   select CASE
     WHEN b.length >= 0 and b.length <= 500 THEN '0To500'
     WHEN b.length >= 501 and b.length <= 1000 THEN '501To1000'
     WHEN b.length >= 1001 and b.length <= 2000 THEN '1001To2000'
     WHEN b.length >= 2001 and b.length <= 3000 THEN '2001To3000'
     WHEN b.length >= 3001 and b.length <= 4000 THEN '3001To4000'
     WHEN b.length >= 4001 and b.length <= 5000 THEN '4001To5000'
     WHEN b.length >= 5001 and b.length <= 6000 THEN '5001To6000'
     WHEN b.length >= 6001 and b.length <= 7000 THEN '6001To7000'
     WHEN b.length >= 7001 and b.length <= 8000 THEN '7001To8000'
     WHEN b.length >= 8001 and b.length <= 99999 THEN '8001To99999'
     END AS RangeOfLength,
   w.report_plant,
   w.volume,
   y.Cod
   from T56W w, T56X x, T56Y y, T57B b
      where w.PART_NBR = x.PART_NBR 
   AND w.PLANT_ID = x.PLANT_ID
   AND x.BF = y.BF 
   AND x.PART_NBR = y.PART_NBR
   AND x.PLANT_ID = y.PLANT_ID
   AND y.Cod = b.Cod
   AND y.PLANT_ID = b.PLANT_ID)
      GROUP BY report_plant, RangeOfLength
      ORDER BY 1) Qry1
      PIVOT (SUM(vol) FOR Plant
      IN ('Plant 1' as "P1",
        'Plant 2' as "P2",
        'Plant 3' as "P3",
        'Plant 4' as "P4",
        'Plant 5' as "P5",
        'Plant 6' as "P6",
        'Plant 7' as "P7"
    )) pvt
```

La consulta anterior me devuelve algo como esto:

[image: Imagen2]

Como puedo agrupar por RangeOfLent en el Pivor?
Otra cosa, la columna de Volume, que es el volumen total por RangeOfLength, no me aparece despues de la modificacion, como la puedo agregar?

Saludos

DS